# BLENDER - COMBINING OBJECTS (CTRL+J) MESS UP QUALITY

Tags: object, merge, blender, mesh

ive created a humanoid character (.blend file), note that every part of the object is separate as shown below  in the Figure 1.

[image: Outline Properties Tree]

I tried to merge every thing together but unfortunately one hand and one leg seems to lose some quality (see Figure 2).

[image: merged object]

My question is how to combine those objects together without losing quality?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. There is an Exchange dedicated to Blender though, you might want to check there what sorts of questions they welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your normals are flipped. (you're talking about the black parts right)

Try this. enter edit mode, then a (to select everything) then click ctrl N to flip normals.

Comment: Yeap, you are right. I fliped the direction of the normals

Answer (score 0):

Flipping the normals facing inwards the mesh fixed the above problem
[image]